# Oracle data access with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting a 424 error when setting my con object

```
Dim con As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim query As String
Set con = CreateObject(ADODB.Connection)
Set rs = CreateObject(ADODB.Recordset)

strCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(jdbc:oracle:thin" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
"(HOST=somehost)(PORT=10080))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=somename))); uid=uid; pwd=pwd;"
```

could anyone let me no what i am doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```